# window.open twice not working (second window doesn't appear) - Blocker workaround

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with this easy thing, must be silly stuff I'm not seeing:

Why this script doesn't work?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");
window.open("http://www.yahoo.com","_blank");
}
</script>
```

The second window doesn't appear.

EDIT: the problem is that the navigators block the second window. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Your second window might be getting blocked by a popup blocker.  Most browsers/users don't like it when websites start opening multiple popups!

Comment: For me Google opened in a new tab and Yahoo (and any further windows) in a new window.

Comment: In Chome, I saw `google.com` open in a new window (tab), and a message saying that `yahoo.com` was blocked by the popup blocker.

Comment: ohhmmmm, see? silly stuff, I'm checking the blocker.

Comment: It's the popup blocker, so any workaround?

Comment: If there were a workaround, why would the blocker exist in the first place!

Comment: @KevinB: That might not work.  Most popup blockers only allow popups if they are triggered via a "click" event.  I don't think it'll allow them from a timeout.

Comment: I tried before posting the question, don't work.

Comment: Chances are, there is no workaround (other than asking the user to allow your site to open popups or disable the popup blocker completely).  Why do you want to have 2 popups anyway?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Open two different documents (check print version and a register). I think I'm using two buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is probably a workaround. However, browsers actively try to to prevent a webpage from opening multiple new tabs, as it this can be abused and generally decreases the quality of the user experience.

As I said, there are probably workarounds, but they are complex and can be patched whenever. There are also companies whose full business model is to sell these workarounds.